# Is it ok to advertise related area51 sites on meta?

Tags: discussion

There are at least two area51 sites at the moment that are likely to interest users of this site.

Is it ok to open a meta thread to advertise?

If yes, should there be a single meta thread for all such advertisements?

For example, compare the following thread that advertises the chemistry proposal on metaphysics:

https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/687/area51-proposal-on-chemistry-is-in-commitment-phase

Comment: The only related SE site that I could think of is linguistics.SE. Do you have more examples?

Comment: @Tim Well, my own proposal, of course: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31886/mathematics-in-german

Comment: I even follow that proposal -- how could I miss it?

Comment: I guess http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2761/natural-language-processing-and-computational-linguistics-nlp-cl is of minor interest here

Answer (score -1):

Just let us try it, more than being close can't happen.

Here is the proposal for the Dutch language:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27557/dutch-language-usage